# Flutter Image.network test fails because of exception

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, end-to-end, flutter-exception

I use Image.network to display images of items:

```
Image.network(
  pictureUri,
  errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => Image.asset(
    noPictureAssetUri,
  ),
);
```

when given item has an image, then the server returns that image, if the item has no image, then the server returns error 404.

It works fine in release mode - if there is image, it is displayed, and if server sends 404, then it uses the asset.

However when I'm running integration tests (flutter test integration_test), they show:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
> HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404,

and then it fails:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following message was thrown:
> Multiple exceptions (5) were detected during the running of the current test, and at least one was
> unexpected.

The tests fails despite everything working as intended.

**How can I make my tests pass? I need either:**

- **a way to catch these internal exceptions**
- **make flutter test ignore
  these exceptions.**

**I want to add that this is an end to end test, running on real (development) server, so I can't just mock http Client as it was suggested. I need a way to handle 404 error, when the real server returns it in debug mode.**

My flutter doctor, in case you need it:

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.963], locale en-150)

> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)

> [√] Chrome - develop for the web

> [√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)

> [√] VS Code (version 1.74.2)

> [√] Connected device (4 available)

> [√] HTTP Host Availability

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Widget Tests with NetworkImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166234/flutter-widget-tests-with-networkimage)

Comment: @SahdeepSingh no, it does not